# TextView is cut off when applying BlurMaskFilter

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to blur the text of a TextView, but the text is cut off left and right.

**Image of the cut off text**

[image]

I tried to increase padding, margin. Changed gravity, Enabled/disabled font padding. Set a fixed height, lowered font size etc. All to the same result: The sides were cut off.

The setting of the mask filter is just two lines:

```
textView.paint.maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)
textView.postInvalidate()
```

This is how my XML layout looks like:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"              
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    tools:textColor="@color/solid_white"
    tools:text="132" />
```

I'm looking for a solution to see the text fully without cutoffs on the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this attribute from your `<TextView>` tag:

> ```
> android:layerType="software"
> ```

Hardware acceleration is required for views to draw outside of their bounds. Note that padding doesn't help here because view contents are clipped by padding as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me.. My (rather hacky) solution is now to add a space before and after the text, which works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting a ton of alternatives, using a `LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(margin)` to offset the text did the trick. I overrode the class and added the blur mask there rather than using a `MaskFilterSpan`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method to make it blurred. Additional benefit is that it can be used on other View types and ViewGroups.

```
view.setRenderEffect(RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(15f, 15f, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP))
```

It can be drawn on padding

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:padding="5dp"
```